# Have I hit a limit here by using hashtags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, hashtag

I'm trying to avoid the use of javascript for things that can be achieved with CSS only (I don't want to go into why too much here, just want to focus on the problem I'm having). As a result, I've developed a modal feature to my site that opens using hashtags and targets (similar to this: http://codepen.io/maccadb7/pen/nbHEg).

That's fine; works how I'd want it to. The problem now is that I want to put a CSS-only tab control inside the modal div. The only methods I've seen this involve the use of hashtags and targets (just as my modal did, and already has). I can't have multiple hashtags in the URL - so am I left with no choice but to use javascript now?

Comment: Adding some example code would surely be helpful.

Comment: I disagree. Regardless - refer to this example: http://codepen.io/maccadb7/pen/nbHEg Assume my code is identical if you must.

Comment: Please post code *here*, not on some 3rd party site.

Comment: Do we all of a sudden disapprove of links to jsfiddle etc.? Please read what I'm asking; no further details of code will help - I'm asking about the limitation of hashtags in the way that I'm attempting to use them.

Comment: @DeeMac - disapprove, no- however the point of SO is as a *self contained* Q/A site, which is why one of the close reasons explicitly states the lack of relevant code provided in the question, SO is for code-related issues, which is why code should be a prominent part of the question, the site works on the assumption the question still stands alone if the links are subject to linkrot in future

Comment: @SW4 - it is never the case that code should consistently be part of the question on SO, there are many many technical questions that don't involve code. I've referenced an example to serve it's purpose as a bit more context, if necessary. But anything 'core' to what I'm asking here is listed in my OP, it is self-contained. If that link should be removed now I see no reason the question still couldn't be answered by somebody who knows the answer, it's merely to provide some more context.

Comment: i would rather have an external link to see it in its entirety while beeing able to play around with it without storing it on my drive somewhere. however i do prefer sites i already know, because i'm paranoid about clicking new sites without VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this, relatively positioned box holding absolutely positioned tabs and inline radio inputs and `+` in the selector to choose the visible one

```html
<div class="tabbox">
    <label for="tab1">A</label>
    <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tab" class="tabchoice" />
    <div class="tabcontent">hello</div>
    <label for="tab2">B</label>
    <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tab" class="tabchoice" />
    <div class="tabcontent">world</div>
</div>
```

```css
.tabbox {
    position: relative;
}
.tabcontent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
.tabchoice:checked + .tabcontent {
    display:block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JbgG4/)

You might need to do a bit more work for overflows etc, in production code

Comment: Again, brilliant answer. Just what I was after. I'll try both solutions and mark accordingly shortly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Purely for how succinct it is I'm opting for this solution. Spot on mate. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use radio buttons and a lot of css to create a non javascript tab control

```
<div id="content">
    <label class="what-tab" for="what-tab">What is </label>
    <label class="example-tab" for="example-tab">Examples</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="example-tab"/>
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="what-tab" checked=""/>
    <div id="group">
         <div id="what">What</div>
         <div id="example">Example</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#content label{
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
}
#content label:hover{
    color: white;
}
[name=tab]{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.what-tab{
    background-color: green;
}
.example-tab
{
    background-color: blue;
}
#group{
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 525px;
}
#group > div{
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
#what{
    border: solid 1px blue;
}
#example{
    border: solid 1px green;
}
#example > label{
    background-color: green;
}
#example > div{
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px;
    display:none;
    clear:both;
}
#example-tab:checked ~ #group #example{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
#what-tab:checked ~ #group #what{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
input[name="eg-tab"]{
    display:none;
}
input + div{
    clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FPD58/2/

Comment: This is brilliant! Exactly what I was after. I'll give it a go in the context of my solution now.

Comment: You can shorten this a little by doing something like `input:checked + * + * + * + * + div`, if there is always certain offset between your option and the tab it represents